# Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to download a picture from the local storage LCI command Laravel, but I get the error:

```
 ErrorException 

  Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse could not be converted to int

  at D:\code\wtf2\APP_NAME\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:136
    132▕     protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    133▕     {
    134▕         $method = method_exists($this, 'handle') ? 'handle' : '__invoke';
    135▕
  ➜ 136▕         return (int) $this->laravel->call([$this, $method]);
    137▕     }
    138▕
    139▕     /**
    140▕      * Resolve the console command instance for the given command.

  1   D:\code\wtf2\APP_NAME\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:136
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError()

  2   D:\code\wtf2\APP_NAME\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:256
      Illuminate\Console\Command::execute()
```

my code handle command

```
public function handle()
    {
        $filename = 'tes38C.jpg';

        $path = Storage::path('public/' .$filename);
        return response()->download($path, $filename, ['Content-Type' => $filename]);


    }
```

but when download file from the web service everything is fine

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by casting to an integer?

Comment: I am trying to get an image from local storage, if I use localhost then the file is uploaded in downloads, similarly I want to do it CLI

Comment: As a sidenote, perhaps you want to use `['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']` instead of `['Content-Type' => $filename]`.

Comment: the error disappears but is the file loaded in this case?

Comment: You will have to tell use. Check the destination location `$path`.